# How to Access Spring Configuration Outside a JAR File

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am new with Spring Boot Development and currently can't move-on on the issue of how to load my spring application configuration outside the jar file.

My existing code looks like this

```
private ApplicationContext context;

public static void main(String[] args){
    SpringApplication.run(SMPPEngine.c1ass);
    new SMPPEngine();
}

public SMPPEngine(){
    loadConfiguration();
    process();
}

private void loadConfiguration(){
    context = new ClassPatthlApplicationContext(”application-context.xm1”);
}
```

What I want to achieve is to have the jar file next to application-context.xml in one directory so that when there are configuration changes,I don't need to recompile my code just to reflect the changes on application-context.xml.

Based on what I've read on the internet, this is possible by using  'file://directory/application.xml' instead of classpath. But my problem on using the later is that when you place your jar and file to other location, I am required to do code change to reflect the new directory which does not solve the problem of getting away from code recompilation.

I hope I made my issue clear, and get an immediately response with you guys :)
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches to do this, standard, you can use spring `file:` prefix for accessing filesystem paths.

but with spring boot, you can specifiy it in `application.properties` with

`spring.config.location` propertiy, or you can add it in command line when run the spring boot jar file like 
`java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties`

But for your codes, actually you **do not** need to re-create the spring context from the configuration files, but you want get the context instance, you just need to inject it

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, if you have the infrastructure. Would be to use [Spring Cloud Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/).  After your Boot application is configured to read from it, they can be modified at anytime without recompilation or restarting.